# Zf2 Form Select Disbale Default Option

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to display a default text for the dropdown but I dont want it to be selectable when user clicks on the dropdown:

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'quicksearch',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'empty_option' => 'Quick Search',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '1' => 'Online Now',
                    '2' => 'Most Popular'
                ),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'quicksearch',
                'class' => 'quicksearch selectyze1 comonserchclas',
            ),
        ));
```

In the above I need to display Quick Search as default but not selectable. Is there any option to not display the Quick Search text when user clicks on dropdown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the options array as follows:

```
$options = array( 
    array('value' => '0', 'label' => 'Quick Search', 'disabled' => 'disabled'), 
    array('value' => '1', 'label' => 'Online Now'), 
    array('value' => '2', 'label' => 'Most Popular') 
);
```